# What is the most optimal way to store eventHandlers inside reactor

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Folks, what would be the most optimal data structure to store eventHandlers in the reactor class.
A few details about the event handler.
Every event handler can be registered to listen for a specific event type. Event is a class which has got int32_t type and the virtual method OnMessage(const Message*). Something like this

```
class IEventHandler
{
  int32_t type;
public:
  virtual ~eventHandler() {};
  virtual void OnMessage(const Message *msg) = 0;
};
```

Can I just store event handlers in the vector and sort them by the message type to optimize the search process when event is received or I need to store these in the map. I am trying to find the fastest way
to find an event and call an event handler. When I insert an event I can use std::lower_bound to find the
proper position of the event handler in the vector.

Thanks, folks

Comment: I'd think `std::unordered_map<int32_t, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IEventHandler>>>` should be sufficiently fast and allow multiple handlers for each message type. If you only need one handler per type, you can take out the vector. If the domain of types is consecutive, you could even use an array instead of a map.

Comment: Thany you, cdhowie. I think std::unordered_map<int32_t, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IEventHandler>>> is exactly what I will be looking for. I can have more than one handler registered for a particular type,

Comment: Domain of types is consecutive and moreover the type lies in the range of 32 bit value according to the requierement

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a classical reactor approach according to the original pattern described here:   [Reactor Pattern](https://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/%7Eschmidt/PDF/Reactor.pdf)

I decided for a `std::map`, and use the address of the event handler as a key and the event type as the value. So, an opposite approach than yours.

But this gives me ultra fast access and easy handling. Please have look at:

[My GitHub project](https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/SmlParser) and here specifcally at "reactor.cpp" and "reactor.hpp". By the way. I also developed a "Proactor".

I will paste the "reactor.hpp" and "reactor.cpp" into this thread but please look at my GitHub project.

HPP:

```
// This module implements the “Reactor” design pattern intended for synchronous event handling. The basis 
// for the implementation is the work from Douglas C Schmidt already published 1995 in the course of 
// developing high performance web servers. For a description of Schmidt’s work, please refer to 
// https://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/PDF/Reactor.pdf .
//
// Please note: There is a second design pattern for high load web servers using asynchronous operations: 
// The so called “Proactor” pattern.
//
// The implementation is close to the description of Schmidt. The main elements are:
//
//
// 1.Handle
//
// The “Handle” is simply an already open file descriptor. The “SynchronousEventDemultiplexor” checks, if an 
// “Event” on that descriptor occurred.
//
//
// 2. EventHandler
//
// Owner of a “Handle”. If there is an “Event” for the associated “Handle”, then the “EventHandler” is 
// invoked and deals with that event. The “EventHandler” is implemented as an abstract base class. The 
// main interface consists of:
//    Handle getHandle(void) = 0;
//    EventProcessing::Action handleEvent(const EventType eventType) = 0;
// The “handleEvent” function is called by the “InitiationDispatcher” through the “SyncronousEventDemultiplexor”.
// This is implemented using a call back mechanism.
//
//
// 3. ConcreteEventHandler
//
// The “ConcreteEventHandler” is derived from the abstract “EventHandler”. It finally provides the 
// functionality needed. An example is the “CommunicationEndPoint” class which is itself an abstract 
// base class for specific communication instances using serial ports or sockets. All of them have to 
// implemented the “handleEvent” function and do the appropriate things for the “Event”.
//
//
// 4. InitiationDispatcher
//
// The “InitiationDispatcher” is a container for “EventHandler”s. “EventHandler”s can be registered and
// unregistered with the “InitiationDispatcher”. The “InitiationDispatcher” will handle the events through
// the “SyncronousEventDemultiplexor”. It is providing the call back functionality. The main interface is:
//    void registerHandler(EventHandler *ev, EventType et);
//    void unregisterHandler(EventHandler *ev);
//    EventProcessing::Action handleEvents(void);
// Interested components will register their “EventHandler”s. The “InitiationDispatcher” will then take care 
// for handling all upcoming “Events”. Eventually the call back function along with the found “Events” will 
// be called. Of course “EventHandlers” that are not needed any longer can be unregistered.
//
//
// 5. SynchronousEventDemultiplexor
// 
// The “SynchronousEventDemultiplexor” uses operation system support to detect activities on “Handle”s. 
// It is a blocking entity and waits for something to happen. Then the Event is de-multiplexed and assigned
// to the corresponding “EventHandler”. 
//
// Since operating systems have different mechanism to implement such functionality we use a static Strategy 
// Pattern to define and use the most fitting solution. Many operating systems have the function “select” 
// for that purpose. Windows uses “WaitForMultipleObjects” and I selected the Linux compatible “poll” function.
// If some other implementation is wished then you should derive a class from 
// “SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementation” and do your own implementation. 
//
//
// 6. Reactor
// 
// All needed and before defined functionalities are wrapped in one class. The Reactor.
// This class serves as the main interface to the outer world.
//
//
// The reactor will be used to listen on raw sockets for network connections, to get data from serial ports or
// other data sources, like pipes or fifos. 

#ifndef REACTOR_HPP
#define REACTOR_HPP

#include "mytypes.hpp"
#include "singleton.hpp"
#include "eventhandler.hpp"



#include <poll.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <map>
#include <vector>
 
 

namespace ReactorInternal
{

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 1. General




    // The "Reactor" pattern registers information about "EventHandler"s and corresponding events.
    // Here we define a  data structure as a helper class for more convenient functionality
    // Definition of ContainerType that will be used to store/register the EventHandler Data
    typedef std::map<EventHandler *,EventType> RegistrationDataContainer;
    typedef std::map<EventHandler *,EventType>::iterator  RdcIterator;


    // The InitiationDispatcher initiates the dispatching of the "EventHandler" and "Events".
    // So here we will register / unregister the list of "EventHandler"s that shall be monitored
    // for certain Events. This is a container class for "EventHandler"s
    // The main function is of course "handleEvents" function which will be implemented by the
    // SynchronousEventDemultiplexor. 
    //
    // As defined by the Reactor pattern their is a strong cooperation
    // between the InitiationDispatcher and the SynchronousEventDemultiplexor. Therefore this class holds
    // a pointer to the SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementation (which is a abstract base class)
    // Meaning: This class will work with all different kinds of implementations for the SynchronousEventDemultiplexor.
    // We are using the "Bridge"-design pattern to realize that

    class SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementation; // Forward Declaration

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 2. Initiation Dispatcher

    class InitiationDispatcher
    {
        public:
            InitiationDispatcher(void);
            // Ctor needs concrete implementation of SynchronousEventDemultiplexor 
            explicit InitiationDispatcher(SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementation *sedi);
            //lint --e{1551,1540}
            //1540 pointer member 'Symbol' (Location) neither freed nor zero'ed by destructor
            //1551 function 'Symbol' may throw an exception in destructor 'Symbol'
            ~InitiationDispatcher(void) { synchronousEventDemultiplexor = null<SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementation *>(); }
            
            // Register an EventHandler. So add it to this class' container 
            void registerHandler( EventHandler *const ev,  const EventType et);
            // Remove EventHandler From container
            void unregisterHandler( EventHandler *const ev);
            
            // Handle events using the SynchronousEventDemultiplexor
            // According to the standard reactor pattern the initiation dispatcher has to dispatch the events
            // Since we want to dcouple functionalities und increase the independence from the OS, we ask
            // the Synchronous Event Demultiplexor and here the specific OS dependent implementation
            // to additionally do the dispatching task. So the Synchronous Event Demultiplexor waits
            // for events to happen, demultiplexs them AND dispatches the event (Call the event handlers) 
            EventProcessing::Action handleEvents(void);

        protected:
            // The container for the EventHandler. Container can be implemented as a vector or a list
            RegistrationDataContainer registrationDataContainer; 
            // After a new "EventHandler" has been added or removed, the SynchronousEventDemultiplexor
            // must be informed about that so that it can build a new "Handle" (descriptor) list
            boolean updateHandler;
            
            // Pointer to the implementation of the SynchronousEventDemultiplexor
            // Bridge Pattern
            SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementation *synchronousEventDemultiplexor;
    };


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 3. Synchronous Event Demultiplexor
    

    // -----------------------------------------------------------
    // 3.1 General Base Class for Synchronous Event Demultiplexors
    

    // Abstract base class for any kind of implementation of the SynchronousEventDemultiplexor
    // As explained above. Different operating systems offer different system calls for a synchronous
    // wait. Since we want to decouple OS specific operations from this function we use the
    // bridge pattern to be able to select appropriate or preferred specific implementations.
    // This base class describes the main public interface for the class
    class SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementation
    {
        public:
            SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementation(void)  {}           // Empty ctor
            virtual ~SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementation(void) {}   // Empty dtor
            // pure virtual interface function to the SynchronousEventDemultiplexor
            // Inform on registered "EventHandler"s and if the container has been updated.
            // Then run the main event loop
            virtual EventProcessing::Action handleEvents(RegistrationDataContainer &rdc, boolean &updateHandler) = 0;
            
            // In case that the SynchronousEventDemultiplexor is interested in these activities
            //lint --e{1961}  //1961 virtual member function 'Symbol' could be made const
            virtual void registerHandlerInfo(EventHandler *const,  const EventType) {}
            virtual void unregisterHandlerInfo( EventHandler *const) {}
    };

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // 3.2 Synchronous Event Demultiplexors using Linux function epoll

    class SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementationUsingEPoll : public SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementation
    {
        public:
        
            typedef struct epoll_event EpollEventData;
            
            // Initialization
            SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementationUsingEPoll(void);
            virtual ~SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementationUsingEPoll(void);
            
            // Register / Unregister Eventhandlers
            virtual void registerHandlerInfo(EventHandler *const eh,  const EventType et) ; 
            virtual void unregisterHandlerInfo( EventHandler *const eh); 
            // Event handler
            virtual EventProcessing::Action handleEvents(RegistrationDataContainer &rdc, boolean &updateHandler);
            
        protected:
            // Handle to the EPOLL functionality itself
            Handle ePollHandle;
            // Persistent data
            EpollEventData epollEventData;
    };


    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // 3.3 Synchronous Event Demultiplexors using Linux function ppoll

    // Concrete implementation of a SynchronousEventDemultiplexor using the Linux ppoll function
    // Decision to use ppoll because ease of use and some advantages over the classical approach with select

    class SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementationUsingPoll : public SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementation
    {
        public:
            SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementationUsingPoll(void);
            //lint -e{1740,1551}
            //1740 pointer member 'Symbol' (Location) not directly freed or zero'ed by destructor
            //1551 function 'Symbol' may throw an exception in destructor 'Symbol'
            virtual ~SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementationUsingPoll(void) { delete [] pollHandleProperty; pollHandleProperty = null<PollHandleProperty *>(); }
            
            // Concrete Implementation of the main "handleEvent" functions
            virtual EventProcessing::Action handleEvents(RegistrationDataContainer &rdc, boolean &updateHandler);
            
        protected:
            typedef struct pollfd       PollHandleProperty;     // struct of file descriptors and event
            typedef struct timespec     PollTimeSpeccification; // Time-out definition (ppoll specific)
                    
            PollHandleProperty *pollHandleProperty;             // Container of descriptors and events
            PollTimeSpeccification pollTimeSpeccification;      // specific time out
            
            // Helper function. After (un)registration of EventHandlers the container of descriptors and events
            // needs to be rebuild
            // updateHandler is an indicator, that the list has to be updated
            void updatePollHandlerPropertyList(RegistrationDataContainer &rdc, boolean &updateHandler);
    };
            

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 4. Reactor
            
            
    // The Reactor
    //
    // The Reactor class is implemented as an Template. The template Parameter is the implementation method
    // of the "SynchronousEventDemultiplexor".
    //
    // The "Reactor" contains the InitiationDispatcher and the "SynchronousEventDemultiplexor" as well as the
    //    handleEvents, registerHandler, unregisterHandler
    // 
    // We use the Facade Pattern here to wrap every other functionality just in one class.
    //
    // Additionally: The Reactor is implemented using a Singleton 

    template <class SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementationUsingMethod>
    class ReactorBase
    {
        public:
            ~ReactorBase(void) {}
            ReactorBase<SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementationUsingMethod>(void) : 
                                                    synchronousEventDemultiplexor(), 
                                                    initiationDispatcher(&synchronousEventDemultiplexor) {}
                                                    
            // Wrapper functions for initiationDispatcher
            EventProcessing::Action handleEvents(void) { return initiationDispatcher.handleEvents(); }
            void registerHandler( EventHandler *const ev,  const EventType et) { initiationDispatcher.registerHandler(ev, et); }
            void unregisterHandler( EventHandler *const ev) { initiationDispatcher.unregisterHandler(ev); }
            
            // Singleton, generates one and only pointer to this class
            SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(ReactorBase<SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementationUsingMethod>)
            
        protected:
            SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementationUsingMethod synchronousEventDemultiplexor;
            InitiationDispatcher initiationDispatcher;
    };

}


    // Select implementation and create a short name

    //typedef ReactorInternal::ReactorBase<ReactorInternal::SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementationUsingPoll> Reactor;
    typedef ReactorInternal::ReactorBase<ReactorInternal::SynchronousEventDemultiplexorImplementationUsingEPoll> Reactor;


    // Shortcut functions
    inline void reactorRegisterEventHandler(EventHandler *const eh, const EventType et) {Reactor::getInstance()->registerHandler(eh,et);} 
    inline void reactorUnRegisterEventHandler(EventHandler *const eh) {Reactor::getInstance()->unregisterHandler(eh);} 


#endif
```

---

I cannot paste the CPP. SO does not allow long texts

---

Comment: Thanks, Armin. I will definitely look at your proactor. This is the next thing that I will be trying to implement. Why did you decide to use std::map. You could have used multimap and instead of using address as a key you could have used type as a key